# Best practice for copying static content between a web project and a self hosted EXE project

Tags: asp.net

I have a visual studio solution that has, amongst other project the following three:

- **NamespacePrefix.NancyFX.csproj:** Some Nancy modules
- **NamespacePrefix.NancyFX.IISHosting.csproj:** A web solution to host the nancy modules
- **NamespacePrefix.NancyFX.Selfhost.csproj:** An exe to host the nancy modules

In addition to rest services there is some html javascript and css in the Views/, Scripts/, and Content/ folders. I want this content in both the IIS Hosting and the Self hosting project. Currently I store the files in the Web project, and copy them over to the self hosting project bu editing the csproj xml like so:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">                                                                                            
  <ItemGroup>                                                                                                          
    <ContentItems Include="..\NamespacePrefix.NancyFX.IISHosting\Content\**\*.*" />                                     
    <ScriptItems Include="..\NamespacePrefix.NancyFX.IISHosting\Scripts\**\*.*" />                                      
    <ViewItems Include="..\NamespacePrefix.NancyFX.IISHosting\Views\*.*" />                                             
  </ItemGroup>                                                                                                         
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ContentItems)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\Content\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ScriptItems)" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)\Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" /> 
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewItems)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)\Views" />                                           
</Target>
```

This works fine, but is there a better way? This seems to give me the best intellisense, etc.

Comment: Is it not enough to reference the same folders/files by using `Add` -> `Existing item...` option?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about reviewing code. Might be a better fit for Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Malachi how is this a superuser question? I'm hand editing a .csproj file, which is written in msbuild. Msbuild is a turing complete declarative DSL that runs from the command line and Visual Studio. Despite it being just a DSL, I can call any CLR method from it. I have working code, but I want to see if I'm doing it the best way. That seems like a code review question. If not, its a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I guess a build XML-file is a border case between Programmers and Code Review. I don't think this is a SO question since you don't have an actual *problem*, but just want to know if there's a better way. I personally feel that your question is more related to the structure of your solution than actual code, and therefore I think you should try Programmers. If you don't get any help there (which I doubt), let us know and your question will likely be re-opened. Otherwise, feel free to start a discussion about this on our [meta].

Comment: @JustinDearing, I reread the question, it's not a superuser question, *I should't skim so fast*, it is a Programmers question though. this is about design and not about review of code, does that make sense?

Comment: @JustinDearing Does the following answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11808911/49942